# Matlab Arrayfun with Handle Class

Tags: matlab

Say I have a 1x2 object array of a handle class with a method SetProperty. Can I use arrayfun to call the SetProperty method for each class, along with a vector for it to use to set the property value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
arrayfun(@(x,y)x.SetProperty(y), yourHandleObjects, theValues)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is straightforward, I have no idea why I was having so much trouble with the syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You can also design the class so that the call to `SetProperty` will be vectorized:

```
 class Foo < handle
      methods(Access=public)
            function SetProperty(this,val)
                 assert(numel(this)==numel(val));
                 for i=1:numel(this)
                      this(i).prop = val(i);
                 end
            end
      end
end
```

Then, you can create a vector and call the method on it directly:

```
    f = repmat(Foo(),[1 2]);
    f.SetProperty( [5 3]);
```

Comment: I've used this before too. I'm more motivated to use arrayfun now, though, because I can control what gets passed to the function. This was an issue when I had a bunch of nested classes, and I never knew if self was going to refer to the class I wanted or its superclass, which depended on from where I called the method.

Comment: @AndrewAshworth what you are saying sounds interesting. Can you give an example? (For my own education purposes)